# Environment variables saved in cmd but not in .bat

Tags: windows, matlab, batch-file, cmd, environment

I want to run a program using a specific set of environment variables.

My .bat file looks like this:

```
/c cd "C:\Program Files\My\Software"
/c setup_env.bat
matlab
```

When i run it in that order in cmd it works (both as single lines and .bat) but when I run the .bat file outside cmd (eg. double click) it runs matlab but without the environment variables set.

What can I do to make it do the same when i execute in from the graphical environment?

Comment: I suppose, the line starts with `/c` is a typo, as this aren't valid commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to start a batch file from your batch file you should do that with a `CALL setup_env.bat`, else the setup_env will not return to the caller script

Answer (score 0):

If you want MATLAB to have special environment variables set, you can set them in MATLAB using the [setenv](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setenv.html) function.
You could add this in your MATLAB [startup](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/startup.html) file in this case.

And use a MATLAB Shortcut with a Start-in directory pointing to where this startup file is located.

That would do more or less what your .bat file is doing but with a customized MATLAB shortcut.